# How to do "live request batching" in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes

Here is my situation:

- I have a rather slow tensorflow model that runs on GPU (2 to 3 seconds per prediction)
- A prediction for a single 'entity' vs a prediction for 8 'entities' takes about the same time
- This means I could be 8 times as efficient by simply combining multiple predictions in the same request
- I have a service on AI platform serving requests to that model
- The service works for slow request rates but has trouble scaling up (anything over 4 QPS is too much to handle)

My question then is:
Is there a standard way / best practice for batching live client requests:

- When receiving a request, wait a little bit for other requests
- After a while, or when the number of requests reaches a set number, forward the requests in a single "batch" to another service.
- If traffic is low, the delay will expire before the batch is full, but since traffic is low, that's not an issue
- If traffic is high, the batch will be full before the delay, and the client will have to wait less

I have an almost-working solution with app-engine + firebase (for hosting the shared 'queue') but implementing the delay is giving me trouble (app engine doesn't seem to like python's threading.Timer

I'd appreciate something that could work with app engine, but at this point I'm open to any suggestions (as long as it is applicable on google cloud).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The perfect (but not the cheapest) is to use Dataflow.

- When a prediction request comes in, publish it in PubSub
- Deploy a dataflow in streaming mode, with fixed windows of X minutes, and another trigger, not accumulated, after Y event in the window.
- When a window trigger is performed (either on the number of messages or on the timer) do the batch processing

---

You can imagine other designs, simpler/cheaper.

- Still publish the prediction requests in PubSub

1. You can schedule a Cloud Functions, or a Cloud Run every X minutes to pull the pubsub subscription and then to trigger the batch job. But, it's a fixed time.
2. When you publish the message in PubSub, you can also store, in firestore for example, and increase a counter and the date of the 1st message published in PubSub.

   - If the number of message is above your threshold, perform a request to your other process that pull the PubSub subscription and run the batch processing (as before #1). Reset the counter value and the message date value
   - Set up a cloud scheduler which check, every minute, the value of the 1st message date in Firestore. If it's above your time limit, perform a request to your other process that pull the PubSub subscription and run the batch processing (as before #1). Reset the counter value and the message date value

The #2 will generate a lot of Firestore read/write, but will be cheaper than dataflow.

Comment: Thanks! ... but if I understand correctly, the minimum delay with all of these solutions is around a minute. I had a similar idea using cron jobs, but I fear waiting a whole minute for results is going to be too long for users (who will expect to wait 5, maybe 10 seconds)

Comment: You have several solutions. One is to trigger every minute a process (Cloud Function or Cloud Run) and the process perform a check every 5 seconds. The principle is that all the checks, during 1 minutes, need to be performed in a request context. The other solution is to have a process that create Cloud Task with a trigger time stamp in the task. Every minute, generate 12 tasks, each separate of 5 seconds. The task will call another endpoint that perform the check and the batch triggering.

Comment: I didn't know about cloud tasks 'scheduleTime'. That sounds like a solution (although a bit "hacky"). I'll give it a try. Thanks!